'p-carousel is not a known element' error when integrating PrimeNG Carousel
I'm having issues with PrimeNG's p-carousel when trying to set up a circular carousel. I imported the CarouselModule into my component's module as recommended, I copied the TypeScript code, but when inserting the HTML code into my component's template, an error is displayed: 'p-carousel' is not a known element,I think I have done everything necessary for imports or other, and here are my different codes: HTML, TS, the module, and the error
Here is my HTML code :
<div class="contenair">
<div class="card">
    <p-carousel 
        [value]="products" 
        [numVisible]="3" 
        [numScroll]="3" 
        [circular]="true" 
        [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions" 
        autoplayInterval="3000">
        <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
                <div class="border-1 surface-border border-round m-2 p-3">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <div class="relative mx-auto">
                            <img 
                                src="https://primefaces.org/cdn/primeng/images/demo/product/{{ product.image }}" 
                                [alt]="product.name" 
                                class="w-full border-round" />
                            <p-tag 
                                [value]="product.inventoryStatus" 
                                [severity]="getSeverity(product.inventoryStatus)" 
                                class="absolute" 
                                [ngStyle]="{ 'left.px': 5, 'top.px': 5 }" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 font-medium">
                        {{ product.name }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="mt-0 font-semibold text-xl">
                        {{ '$' + product.price }}
                    </div>
                        <span>
                            <p-button icon="pi pi-heart" severity="secondary" [outlined]="true" />
                            <p-button icon="pi pi-shopping-cart" styleClass="ml-2" />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
    </p-carousel>
</div>

Here is my TS code:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/demo/api/product';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/demo/service/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carousel',
  templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
  styleUrl: './carousel.component.scss'
})
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit{
  products: Product[] | undefined;

responsiveOptions: any[] | undefined;

constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProductsSmall().then((products) => {
        this.products = products;
    });

   this.responsiveOptions = [
        {
            breakpoint: '1199px',
            numVisible: 1,
            numScroll: 1
        },
        {
            breakpoint: '991px',
            numVisible: 2,
            numScroll: 1
        },
        {
            breakpoint: '767px',
            numVisible: 1,
            numScroll: 1
        }
    ];
}

getSeverity(status: string) {
    switch (status) {
        case 'INSTOCK':
            return 'success';
        case 'LOWSTOCK':
            return 'warning';
        case 'OUTOFSTOCK':
            return 'danger';
        default: return "Info"
    }
}

}
Here is my module code :
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CarouselRoutingModule } from './carousel-routing.module';
import { CarouselComponent } from './carousel.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [CarouselComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CarouselRoutingModule,
    CarouselModule
  ]
})
export class CarouselModule { 
  
}

Here is the full error code
Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:3:9 - error NG8001: 'p-carousel' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

  3         <p-carousel
            ~~~~~~~~~~~
  4             [value]="products"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
  8             [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  9             autoplayInterval="3000">
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:4:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

4             [value]="products"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:5:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'numVisible' since it isn't a 
known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'numVisible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

5             [numVisible]="3"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:6:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'numScroll' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'numScroll' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

6             [numScroll]="3"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:7:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'circular' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'circular' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

7             [circular]="true"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:8:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'responsiveOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'responsiveOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

8             [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.




** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


× Failed to compile.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

72 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2024-09-10T14:00:23.994Z - Hash: 34e2d77cbc25ef2d - Time: 1585ms

Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:3:9 - error NG8001: 'p-carousel' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

  3         <p-carousel
            ~~~~~~~~~~~
  4             [value]="products"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
  8             [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions"
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  9             autoplayInterval="3000">
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:4:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

4             [value]="products"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:5:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'numVisible' since it isn't a 
known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'numVisible' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

5             [numVisible]="3"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:6:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'numScroll' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'numScroll' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

6             [numScroll]="3"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:7:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'circular' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'circular' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

7             [circular]="true"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.


Error: src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.html:8:13 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'responsiveOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'p-carousel'.
1. If 'p-carousel' is an Angular component and it has 'responsiveOptions' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-carousel' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

8             [responsiveOptions]="responsiveOptions"
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/demo/components/pages/carousel/carousel.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './carousel.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CarouselComponent.




× Failed to compile.


What could be causing this problem?

I am waiting for your response to help me resolve this issue.










Have you imported the CarouselModule into your component (for standalone) or the module that declares your component (for modules)?

It would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem or error you're encountering, ideally in an online code editor like Stackblitz.

You must import the carouselmodule in the app.module.ts
import { CarouselModule } from 'primeng/carousel';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Your components
  ],
  imports: [
    CarouselModule,  // Add this line to ensure CarouselModule is imported
    // Other modules
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


I made changes to the question by adding my different files, you can view them up there
